Isometry of balls in residually finite groups
A finitely generated group is called residually finite if there exists a sequence of normal subgroups of finite index whose intersection is trivial. I am to prove the following: "Let $G$ be a residually finite group and let $N_{i} \subseteq G$ be a sequence of finite index subgroups with trivial intersection such that $N_{i} \subseteq N_{j}$ whenever $J\leq i$. Then for every $R > 0$ there exists $i_{0} \in \Bbb N$ such that $B_{G}(e,R)$ is isometric to $B_{G/N_{i}}(e,R)$ for all $i \geq i_{0}$". While working with some concrete examples, I guess that we have to choose (and we can) $i_{0}$ such that $|G/N_{i_{0}}| > 2R$ for given $R > 0$. Now if we take an element of length $l$, it has to be preserved in the ball of the quotient group. I do not see how I may proceed further. More precisely, suppose $g \in B_{G}(e,R)$ is expressed as $s_{1}^{k_{1}}s_{2}^{k_{2}}.....s_{m}^{k_{m}}$, where $s_{i}$ are generators and $\Sigma |k_{i}| = l$. The element $gN_{i_{0}}$ in $B_{G/N_{i_{0}}}(e,R)$ will become $s_{1}^{k_{1}}s_{2}^{k_{2}}.....s_{m}^{k_{m}}N_{i_{0}}$. It may so happen that some of the generators are elements of $N_{i_{0}}$, but under the given conditions, I have to show that the word length is preserved.

We have $$d_{G/N_i}(aN_i,bN_i)=\inf\{d_{G}(a,bx)|x\in N_i\}$$ as a word $w$ in the generators satisfies $waN_i=bN_i$ if and only if $wa=bx$ for some $x\in N_i$.
We may choose $i_0$ sufficiently large that $$B_G(e,4R)\cap N_{i_0}=\{e\},$$ as balls contain finitely many elements.
Then for $i\geq i_0$, if $a,b\in B_G(e,R)$ and $wa=bx$ for some $x\in N_i$, then $x=b^{-1}wa$, so if $x\neq e$ we have the length of $w$ must be at least $4R-2R=2R$.
Thus for $x\in N_i \backslash \{e\}$:  $$d_G(a,b)\leq 2R\leq d_G(a,bx).$$
Thus
$$d_{G/N_i}(aN_i,bN_i)=\inf\{d_{G}(a,bx)|x\in N_i\}=d_G(a,b).$$
We may conclude that the map sending $a\mapsto aN_i$ is an injective isometry $B_G(e,R)\to B_{G/N_i}(e,R)$.
Finally note this map is surjective, as if $d_{G/N_i}(e,aN_i)<R$, then $wa=x$ for some $w$ a word of length at most $r$ in the generators and $x\in N_i$.  Then we have $w(ax^{-1})=e$ and $ax^{-1}\mapsto aN_i$, with $ax^{-1}\in B_G(e,R)$.

"We may choose $i_0$
sufficiently large that
$B_G(e,4R)∩N_{i_0} = {e},$
as balls contain finitely many elements" - Can you expand this a little? I sort of get the geometric intuition but am not able to prove this.

The ball $B_G(e,4R)$ contains finitely many elements $g_1,\cdots,g_n$.  As the intersection of the $N_i$ is empty, for each $k=1,\cdots,n$ we have some $i_k$ such that $g_k\notin N_{i_k}$.  Then just let $i_0$ be the maximum of $i_1,\cdots,i_n$.
